# Update Google Doc with Drive API - Format lost

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to develop a Java program which retrieves a file from the Google Drive and try to reupload it "as is". However, during that process, It loses the format.

Here is how I retrive the file:

```
private static java.io.File downloadFile(File uploadedFile)
        throws IOException {
    java.io.File downloadedFile = new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle() + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile)) {
        drive.files().export(uploadedFile.getId(), "text/html").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
    }

    return downloadedFile;
}
```

Here is how I update the file:

```
private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, File file, java.io.File newContent) throws IOException {
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/html", newContent);
        return service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
}
```

And here is how I combine those methods (pretty dummy):

```
java.io.File downloaded = downloadFile(files.get(0));
updateFile(drive, files.get(0).getId(), files.get(0), downloaded);
```

This is the file before and after: 
[image: before-after]

The process is fine when I export & re-import the Google file as RTF or PDF, but I really need an editable format. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected outcome. PDFs are one way of ensuring the formats are preserved. For Google Docs, not so much.